# CSS - hover one item and remove content of another item

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I'm working with Wordpress menu where I have classic menu and item's submenus. When I hover some item which has children then submenu will show. The problem is when I have some current page then `li` class is `current-submenu-item` and has arrow in bottom of item. And when I hover another item which has submenu (children) I want to disappear that arrow in bottom of current item and when I unhover it then arrow will show again.

The current item's class is this:

```
li.current-submenu-item a:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    width: 20px;
    content: url("http://elvis.zitnikcreative.cz/wp-content/themes/elvis_theme/img/menu_aktivni_sipka.png");
}
```

[**JsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fozuu6hL/).

I tried something like this:

```
li.menu-item-has-children:hover + .li.current-submenu-item a:after {
    content:"";
}
```

But without result. How can I do that only with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the adjacency selector `+` (exactly like the general adjacency selector `~`) works for *next* sibling only, you need to control this behaviour through the `:hover` state of your parent `ul`, e.g.

```
ul:hover li.current-submenu-item a:after {
    content:"";
}
ul:hover li.current-submenu-item:hover a:after {
    content:url("http://.../menu_aktivni_sipka.png");
}
```

So when you `:hover` the menu *then* hide the arrow *unless* you are also hovering the `.current-submenu-item` item

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fozuu6hL/1/

---

As a side note,  your example could work only when you hover the first `list-item` (as specified above) but you need to remove the extra `.` in front of `li`.

Comment: Thank you and when I would like to disappear arrow only for item which has children? (li class menu-item-has-children)

Comment: are you saying that when you hover *person* the arrow should be visible on *cards*?

Comment: Right, is it possible?